# How to set up registration for event with parallel sessions?

Tags: users, entities

I would like to set up the registration for an event.
During the event there are various parallel sessions.

(I was thinking in using the entity registration module)

Needs / problems encountered:
The (registered) user needs to chose the session he/she would like to attend (shouldn´t be possible to sign in for sessions given at the same time!)
Each session has a maximum capacity.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make a node type for sessions, then add the registration field to it. You should make a small module which compares a time/date range/duration field on your session node types to ensure the user cannot register for sessions that are conflicting.

If you have multiple events on your site, consider making a node-reference field to another node type: "events". Then update your session conflict module to take events into account.

This is for Entity Registration (D7)